# Logistic regression's Confidence interval of odd ratios created by tbl_regression differs from SPSS and logRegBin function

Tags: r, gtsummary

I created a univariate regression table by tbl_regression with codes below:

```
glm.fit.TAG=glm(asian2$sICH ~ asian2$TAG, family=binomial) #mô hình 1
TAGtable <- tbl_regression(glm.fit.TAG, exponentiate = TRUE)%>%
 add_glance_source_note()
```

And here was my result: OR 1,92, 95% CI 1,41 - 2,67.

The problem is this result is slightly different from the result of SPSS or logRegBin function in R. (In fact, two latter results are similar): OR 1,92 but 95% CI 1,40 - 2,64.

This phenomenon has occurred with all my regression table using gtsummary. In my opinion, the cause may be due to rounding in the gtsummary calculation mechanism.
My concern is about what'll happen if true CI is remarkably close to 1, could gtsummary return an incorrect value.

Could anyone give me some useful advices?
Best regard

Answer (score 0):

1. {gtsummary} uses `broom::tidy()` to summarize a model, and it is up to the user to know/understand how the CI calculations are performed (and optionally update the default tidier to use the needed method).
2. The default CI is calculated using likelihood methods. You can learn about the other common methods here https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/144603
3. Even if two statistical programming languages are reporting CIs using the same method, you may see differences in the reported values that arise from different maximization algorithms.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've read about how CI is calculated theoretically but I am new and quite unfamiliar with R. It's my favor if you guide me how to create a function that returns the same result as SPSS and logRegBin function.